# ICs for PAL Hsync and Vsync

Tags: video

[image]

I have taken the circuit above from a [“DIY Pong” tutorial](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/ubs/diy-pong-part-1-of-4-getting-started.822/). The circuit generates the HSync and VSync for a PAL signal.

What are the labels for classification of an IC equivalent of this?

Comment: As a reminder, it's better to help people improve their question and make it on topic, especially with new users. I am clearing out the comments

Answer (score 5):

There are still sync generators such as [NTE7049](https://www.nteinc.com/specs/7000to7099/pdf/nte7049.pdf) available that do both NTSC and PAL.

If your video requirements are simple (with no color) then you'd be much better using an entry level MCU such as the Arduino Nano with the [TV.out library](https://github.com/pkendall64/arduino-tvout).
It can even be done in an ATTiny85.

If 'Pong is your end goal, you could look at [this composite implementation](https://areed.me/posts/2021-07-14_implementing_composite_video_output_using_the_pi_picos_pio/) on the Raspberry Pi Pico RP2040.

Comment: Just a note: video sync generators are pretty much obsolete, because (A) few people are interested in generating analog video, and (B) it's super easy to do with a CPLD or even a microprocessor.  Hence the scarcity of them on the market: in 1990, they were all over the place.

Comment: @TimWescott, of course they are obsolete, but that was not the question, and there are still bound to be folks that need to replace parts in old applications. CPLD and FPGA replacements would IMO be too expensive ...certainly for someone wanting to generate a 'Pong' example. I'd suggest today you could do color 'Pong' on an RP2040 for <$5 ...hard to beat for what you treat as a single component. Here's one 'Pong' implementation: https://areed.me/posts/2021-07-14_implementing_composite_video_output_using_the_pi_picos_pio/

Answer (score 1):

All three of those parts are currently available from stock. Eg.

TLC555IDR (SOIC-8), CD4040BM96 & MC14538BDR2G (SOIC-16)

U3 is not specified as to family etc., but 74HC08 or CD4081BNSR are suitable quad AND gates

It is easy to duplicate the function with a microcontroller, of course.

Comment: Assume the output is black and white with resolution 192 by 256 (the maximum resolution on a PAL TV). If the function can be duplicated with a micro controller does that mean it can be duplicated with a circuit based around  CMOS z80 CPU running at 20Mhz and the Z80's program stored on an ROM chip?

Comment: @Learner Might be better if you had a [CTC](http://www.z80.info/zip/z80ctc.pdf) peripheral chip.

Comment: Your comment is interesting -I never knew that IC existed.But using the circuit (if my idea is correct that a 20Mhz z80 can be used in this way) I outlined above has an advantage-for not much additional circuitry you can draw the stored the pong graphics in the ROM for each scanline along with generating the the Hsync & Vsync signals. In other words the pong graphics can be stored in the existing ROM. I do wonder now, what the simplest pre-1990s chip would be to draw such monochrome graphics(if it exists)instead of using a 20Mhz z80 to draw the graphics and generate the Hsync & Vsync signals.

Comment: @Learner It's very likely possible to do that sort of thing in assembly, counting cycles and writing terse isochronous code.

Comment: Would the circuit, image given in the question,still work if the CD4040 IC is replaced by and equivalent circuit made from three CD4017B decade counters to count the number of vertical lines ?
I don't have a CD4040 IC but have a lot of CD4017B ICs.